# Xcode - Project build and run, but i can no archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

When I open Runner.xcworkspace I can build and run project.

When I open Runner.xcodeproj and I build project I have error: Module 'connectivity' not found.

I must update version app in app store but i can't click **Product > Archive**

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Runner.xcworkspace and click Product > Archive

Comment: I have grayed out button Archive

Comment: could you add any screenshots?

Comment: @Dinesh you must select an iOS device. Archive is button is disabled for Simulator. Once you select "Any IOS Device" target, you should be able to see the Archive button.

Answer (score -1):

In order to "archive" your product, you have to connect a real device to your computer. Xcode needs a real device to compile the archive. After connecting a real device (iPhone, iPad) the "grayed out" menu option "Archive" will be no longer grayed out.